# Express any number as the sum of four prime numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I was give a problem to express any number as sum of four prime numbers.

Conditions:

- Not allowed to use any kind of database.
- Maximum execution time : 3 seconds
- Numbers only till 100,000
- **If the splitting is NOT possible, then return -1**

What I did :

1. using the sieve of Eratosthenes, I calculated all prime numbers till the specified number.
2. looked up a concept called Goldbach conjecture which expresses an **even** number as the summation of two primes.

However, I am stuck beyond that.
Can anyone help me on this one as to what approach you might take?

The sieve of Eratosthenes is taking two seconds to count primes up to 100,000.

Comment: This is obviously false for all numbers < 8.

Comment: Can you please tell us the range of that "any number" for example 1 cannot be expressed as a sum of 4 prime numbers. Also the cap would be nice.
Btw, sounds like homework.

Comment: Andreas has a good point. Since 1 is not technically a prime, the smallest sum of four primes is 8. Hence you cannot represent 7 in this way. You also cannot represent the even number two as the sum of two primes.

Comment: I'm guessing this might be the original question:  The Goldbach conjecture says that all positive even integers greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes. Given an input parameter N (odd or even), express N as the sum of four primes (not necessarily distinct) or report that it is impossible to do so.

Comment: Source: Creative Exersise 39, Introduction to Programing in Java, http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/42sort/

Comment: WarDoGG, if smoore is correct, please edit your question.

Comment: Execution time is not only related to the algorithm itself. It also depends on the machine executing your algorithm.

Comment: I love LINQ; pity it has to be c++. =) `var answer = from p in primes from q in primes from r in primes from s in primes where p + q + r + s == n where p <= q && q <= r && r <= s select new { p, q, r, s };`

Comment: Sorry that was an error on my part to tag it as mathematica. i meant mathematics.

Comment: Two seconds sounds a bit too long for the sieve. Either you have an exceptionally slow machine or you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @UncleBens: 2 seconds is *way* too long for the sieve. Mine takes 0.03s, completely unoptimised, on a 2.3GHz processor.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I just wrote a Delphi implementation that takes 0.00047 s on an i7 CPU clocked at 2.93 GHz.

Comment: If it makes any difference, my timing was for the entire program (`time` at the command line). I don't know how long it would take on average if I ran it multiple times, or used `-O`, or fixed the obvious sources of unnecessary work ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Yes, there are probably a number of differences. I only measured the time of the sieve itself, and my CPU was utterly expensive. But anyhow: 2 seconds is obviously ... not good.

Comment: Still, might be fun to see if you can make it fast enough to get a reported time of 0 even with high-performance timers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could still be ok with time. Due to the Goldbach conjecture, Every even Number greater or equal 8 can be expressed as the sum of 2,2, and two further primes. Every odd number greater or equal 9 can be expressed as the sum of 2,3 and two further primes. It shouldn't take too long to figure out the primes.

Edit: Actually, you could speed this up significantly: For any even Number N, find the largest prime that is less or equal N-7 and choose that prime and 3, then look for two further primes to suit your sum. For any odd Number N, find the largest prime greater or equal N-6 and choose it and two, then again choose two primes.

Comment: Even without the edit, the two primes can be found in one double-pass of the list of primes you obtained from the sieve, using two indices/pointers: one going upwards and one going downwards. That should be almost instantaneous, so 2s for the sieving phase is probably fine.

Comment: You're right. I thought that he needed to find these sums for all numbers up to 100k in those 3 seconds. In that case, the speedup could have made the difference.

Answer (score 4):

You can cut down on the range of search needed by noting a simple fact: when you sum up two numbers, the last digit of the sum will be the last digit of the sum of the last digits of the two numbers. For example 2345 + 24323 = 26668 and 5+3=8; If the last digits sum to a 2 digit number, use its last digit eg. 2345+5436=7781 5+6=11 whose last digit is 1.

So, following the algorithm suggested earlier:

1. Compute all primes less than N using the Sieve of Eratosthenes.
2. Tabulate a list of sums of two primes.
3. group into 10 std::set boxes based on last digit
4. Look at the last digit of your number, find the 
   combinations that could make this up (including carry). Use these to limit the range of the search

For example,

1. For a number like 34565, the last digit is 5, the components come from (0,5),(1,4),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1),(5,0),(6,9),(7,8),(8,7),(9,6). Excluding duplicates, we are left with (0,5), (1,4), (2,3), 
   (6,9), (7,8). (Precompute these for all last digits and 
   hardcode into your program).
2. If N is the original number, pick each number M from the "0" box, check if (N-M) is a member of the "5" box etc., for all  possible combinations. If so, you have found your answer!

   - Sreenadh

Comment: "Excluding duplicates, we are left with (0,5), (1,4), (2,3), (6,9), (7,8)", and excluding non-primes we are left with only (2,3) - this is quite a remark and a simple lookup table could speed the whole process up.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood .. the (0,5) refers to the boxes that contain sums of two primes whose last digits are 0 and 5. Sum of two primes could end in 0 eg. 11 and 19

Answer (score 2):

If there weren't the limit on the number size (100,000 or less) then your problem isn't guaranteed to have a solution: see the [weak Goldbach conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#Rigorous_results).

However most likely it's true, at least for numbers within the range of computational results... are you sure your problem isn't to express any number the sum of at *most* four primes?

Since 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23 offer lots of possibilities, I would compute the numbers which are expressed as a sum of 3 of those numbers. (e.g. 2+3+5=10, 2+3+7=2+5+7=12, 3+5+7=15, 2+3+11=16, 2+5+11=18, 3+5+11=19, 2+7+11=20, ... 17+19+23 = 59.)

Then take your arbitrary number N, find the nearest prime below that which differs from N by one of the precomputed sums of 3 small primes. If you don't find a solution, try the next nearest prime up to N-59. If that still doesn't work, start adding in other small primes.

Use the knowledge about [prime gaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) to bound your solution... the largest prime gap for primes below 155921 (greater than 100,000) is 86.

---

p.s. your Sieve of Eratosthenes shouldn't be taking 2 seconds for N=100,000. You only need to check divisors up to the square root of 100,000 = 316.

Comment: If there weren't a limit on the number size, then the 3s time limit would be unreasonable ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a list of primes nad a concrete number isn't this a [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)?

N is your capacity and primes are your items. You have a restriction of 4 on items count. I would go about solving this with dynamic programing, which should be quite fast.

Comment: No offence to you, but I see a tendency in StackOverflow answers to "reduce" problems to *harder* problems. (Hence the frequent unhelpful "this is NP-complete ha ha" answers even to problems which can be solved efficiently for the given constraints.) In this case, there is no need to "reduce" it to knapsack problem, when (because of Goldbach's conjecture etc.) several greedy algorithms will work.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR None taken, this was the first thing that popped into my mind given my knowledge. Without any research this is the solution I could implement without looking anywhere. Of course If I would be faced to solve this I would first google and then ask on SO :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recomendation given by the [question referenced](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/42sort/) in my comments:

> - Compute all primes less than N using
>     the Sieve of Eratosthenes.
> - Tabulate a
>     list of sums of two primes.
> - Sort the
>     list.
> - Check if there are two numbers
>     in the list that sum to N.
> - If so, print out the corresponding four
>     primes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **PHP** implementation that runs in under 2 seconds for n = 99999:

```
function Eratosthenes($number)
{
    static $primes = array();

    if (empty($primes[$number]) === true)
    {
        $sqrt = sqrt($number);
        $primes[$number] = array_merge(array(2), range(3, $number, 2));

        for ($i = 2; $i <= $sqrt; ++$i)
        {
            foreach ($primes[$number] as $key => $value)
            {
                if (($value != $i) && ($value % $i == 0))
                {
                    unset($primes[$number][$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $primes[$number];
}

$time = microtime(true);
$number = 99995;
$primes = array();

if ($number % 2 == 0)
{
    $primes = array(2, 2);
}

else
{
    $primes = array(2, 3);
}

$number -= array_sum($primes);

foreach (Eratosthenes($number) as $prime)
{
    if (in_array($number - $prime, Eratosthenes($number)))
    {
        $primes[] = $prime;
        $primes[] = $number - $prime;

        die(implode(' + ', $primes) . ' (' . (microtime(true) - $time) . ')');
    }
}
```

Of course it won't work with numbers bellow 8 unless you (wrongly) consider 1 as being a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

Just on the subject of the Sieve, here's what I consider an unoptimised, "dumb" implementation:

```
std::vector<int> primes(int n) {
    std::vector<int> s(n+1);
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; ++i) {
        if (s[i] == 0) {
            for (int j = 2*i; j <= n; j += i) {
                s[j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> p;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (s[i] == 0) {
            p.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    // std::copy(p.begin(), p.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    return p;
}
```

For me it runs (with n=100000) in a small fraction of a second.

Answer (score 0):

There is some serious problem with your implementation of the sieve. I just implemented it in Delphi, and on my Intel Core i7 CPU clocked at 2.93 GHz, the time required is less than one millisecond (0.37 ms)!

I used the following code:

```
program Sieve;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

const
  N = 100000;

var
  i, j: integer;
  tc1, tc2, freq: Int64;
  Arr: packed array[2..N] of boolean;

begin

  FillChar(Arr, length(Arr) * sizeof(boolean), 1);

  QueryPerformanceFrequency(freq);

  QueryPerformanceCounter(tc1);
  for i := 2 to N div 2 do
    if Arr[i] then
    begin
      j := 2*i;
      while j <= N do
      begin
        Arr[j] := false;
        inc(j, i);
      end;
    end;

  QueryPerformanceCounter(tc2);
  Writeln(FloatToStr((tc2 - tc1)/freq));

  Writeln;

  for i := 2 to 100 do
    Writeln(IntToStr(i) + ': ' + BoolToStr(arr[i], true));

  Writeln('...');

  Readln;

end.
```

Answer (score -3):

Any number also includes fractionals, so you couldn't express those as primes either. There's other numbers like 9 that you couldn't do. Without 1 as a prime, you can't control it finely.

I expect that the problem does not have a solution.

Comment: `9=2+2+2+3`, four primes, yay =)

Comment: oh come on, the OP probably just neglected to state "integers" instead of "numbers" or another subtle detail of the problem as originally stated.

Comment: Technically, "any number" would also include irrationals and non-real complex numbers, but it is pretty obvious that the OP is only interested in integers...

Comment: And Hamiltonians. Don't forget the Cayley numbers, either - they're always fun since non-associative multiplication pretty much guarantees that you will continually make simple errors...

Comment: Ok, the fractionals thing was supposed to be a joke, but I've been pwned by teh 2+2+2+3 thing. I thought he meant unique.